# How to compile a simple C code with "$gcc test.c -o demo" command?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

On this [beginner tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_programming/computer_programming_syntax.htm) at TutorialsPoint, it says to save the code as test.c and compile it using "$gcc test.c -o demo" command at CMD.

But I don't have $gcc. What is it?

Comment: `$` is your shell prompt, the command is `gcc`.

Comment: `gcc` is a compiler. You can get it for Windows by looking at [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and following the download/install instructions.

Comment: Don't use `gcc test.c -o demo` specially if you are a beginner, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror test.c -o demo`.

Comment: @ouah so $ is used at Unix, while > is used at Windows?

Comment: @R_Kapp will this work? http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/postdownload?source=dlp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split this into parts:

- `$` is a character indicating that the shell is ready to receive a command. It is **not** part of the command.
- `gcc` is an executable executing the GNU C compiler from the GCC toolchain.
- `test.c -o demo` are arguments supplied to `gcc`.

The GCC toolchain is only available natively for GNU systems such as Linux. Using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com/) you can ape its functionality, though.

---

Notes:

- A nice comment, which I second, to your question by @iharob:

  > Don't use `gcc test.c -o demo` specially if you are a beginner, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror test.c -o demo`.

  The additional switches make the compiler point out more warnings.

Answer (score 1):

GCC (GNU Compiler Collection. Upper case.) is a set of compilers, that can compile several languages. 

gcc (lower case) is a command that compile the code you wrote, using the C compiler that GCC includes, into a working C program. Similar commands are g++ for C++ code, gcj for Java code, etc. 

Note GCC is intended for Linux or other Unix-like systems (You can use it in Mac OS X with the help of xcode). If you are using Windows, consider [MinGW] (http://www.mingw.org/) or CygWin https://www.cygwin.com/.

As a beginner, if you still have trouble, consider use Dev-C++, an IDE (integrated development environment) that compiles C and C++. It does all the compiler things for you.